# i want to connect to Oracle database (desktop application) using php on domain? is it possible

Tags: php, oracle

I have to connect my `Oracle` desktop application installed on windows, and I want to query data on the domain and view some data.

For example

`table1 (name, fname, address )` in oracle

```
www.example.com/userinfo.php
```

to view the result from the oracle database installed on windows locally.

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php

Comment: thankx my app database is on my local system and i want a report that is using a domain